# conect if scanresult is in the database

Tags: android, database, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an app in android studio, this app is a barcodescan. Prevuisly you choose what allergies you have in the checkboxactivity, and when you scan a product the app tells you if you can eat it or not. But I don't know how to say this: if the scanresult is in the database of the allergy you can eat it or no. Basically I don't know how to conect de Scanner with the database and the checkbox activities.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_CONFIG =
            "CREATE TABLE " + Configuracio.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    Configuracio._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    Configuracio.LACTOSA + " INTEGER," +
                    Configuracio.GLUTEN + " INTEGER," +
                    Configuracio.NOUS + " INTEGER," +
                    Configuracio.OU + " INTEGER," +
                    Configuracio.CACAUETS + " INTEGER)";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_CONFIG =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Configuracio.TABLE_NAME;

    private static final String SQL_INSERT_CONFIG =
            "INSERT INTO " + Configuracio.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    Configuracio.LACTOSA + ", " +
                    Configuracio.GLUTEN + ", " +
                    Configuracio.NOUS + ", " +
                    Configuracio.OU + ", " +
                    Configuracio.CACAUETS + " ) VALUES (" +
                    0 + ", " +
                    0 + ", " +
                    0 + ", " +
                    0 + ", " +
                    0 + ")";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_CODI =
            "CREATE TABLE " + CodisDeBarra.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    CodisDeBarra._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_PRODUCT + " INTEGER," +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_CODI_DE_BARRES + " INTEGER," +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_LACTOSA + " INTEGER," +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_GLUTEN + " INTEGER," +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_NOUS + " INTEGER," +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_OU + " INTEGER," +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_CACAUETS + " INTEGER)";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_CODI =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CodisDeBarra.TABLE_NAME;

    private static final String SQL_INSERT_CODI_LLET =
            "INSERT INTO " + CodisDeBarra.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_PRODUCT + ", " +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_CODI_DE_BARRES + ", " +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_LACTOSA + ", " +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_GLUTEN + ", " +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_NOUS + ", " +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_OU + ", " +
                    CodisDeBarra.COLUMN_CACAUETS + " ) VALUES (" +
                    "0" + ", " +
                    "8431876100785" + ", " +
                    0 + ", " +
                    0 + ", " +
                    0 + ", " +
                    0 + ", " +
                    0 + ")";


    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CONFIG);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CODI);
        db.execSQL(SQL_INSERT_CONFIG);
       db.execSQL(SQL_INSERT_CODI_LLET);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_CONFIG);
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_CODI);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    public void updateConfig (int lactosa, int gluten, int nous, int ou, int cacauets) {

    }

    public long selectLactosaConfig() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                Configuracio.LACTOSA
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                Configuracio.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
                null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,          // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                   // don't group the rows
                null,                   // don't filter by row groups
                null               // The sort order
        );

        List itemIds = new ArrayList<>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long itemId = cursor.getInt(
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Configuracio.LACTOSA));
            itemIds.add(itemId);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return (long) itemIds.get(0);
    }

    public long selectGlutenConfig() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                Configuracio.GLUTEN
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                Configuracio.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
                null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,          // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                   // don't group the rows
                null,                   // don't filter by row groups
                null               // The sort order
        );

        List itemIds = new ArrayList<>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long itemId = cursor.getInt(
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Configuracio.GLUTEN));
            itemIds.add(itemId);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return (long) itemIds.get(0);
    }

    public long selectNousConfig() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                Configuracio.NOUS
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                Configuracio.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
                null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,          // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                   // don't group the rows
                null,                   // don't filter by row groups
                null               // The sort order
        );

        List itemIds = new ArrayList<>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long itemId = cursor.getInt(
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Configuracio.NOUS));
            itemIds.add(itemId);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return (long) itemIds.get(0);
    }

    public long selectOuConfig() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                Configuracio.OU
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                Configuracio.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
                null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,          // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                   // don't group the rows
                null,                   // don't filter by row groups
                null               // The sort order
        );

        List itemIds = new ArrayList<>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long itemId = cursor.getInt(
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Configuracio.OU));
            itemIds.add(itemId);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return (long) itemIds.get(0);
    }

    public long selectCacauetsConfig() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                Configuracio.CACAUETS
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                Configuracio.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
                null,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,          // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                   // don't group the rows
                null,                   // don't filter by row groups
                null               // The sort order
        );

        List itemIds = new ArrayList<>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long itemId = cursor.getInt(
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Configuracio.CACAUETS));
            itemIds.add(itemId);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return (long) itemIds.get(0);
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class CheckboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Database database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkbox);



        database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        CheckBox gluten = findViewById(R.id.checkboxGluten);
        long glutenVal = database.selectGlutenConfig();
        if (glutenVal == 0) {
            gluten.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            gluten.setChecked(true);
        }

        database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        CheckBox lactosa = findViewById(R.id.checkboxLactosa);
        long lactosaVal = database.selectLactosaConfig();
        if (lactosaVal == 0) {
            lactosa.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            lactosa.setChecked(true);
        }

        database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        CheckBox nous = findViewById(R.id.checkboxNous);
        long nousVal = database.selectNousConfig();
        if (nousVal == 0) {
            nous.setChecked(false);
        } else {
           nous.setChecked(true);
        }

        database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        CheckBox ou = findViewById(R.id.checkboxOu);
        long ouVal = database.selectOuConfig();
        if (ouVal == 0) {
            ou.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            ou.setChecked(true);
        }

        database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        CheckBox cacauets = findViewById(R.id.checkboxCacauets);
        long cacauetsVal = database.selectCacauetsConfig();
        if (cacauetsVal == 0) {
            cacauets.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            cacauets.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;

public class Scanner extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    private boolean grantResults;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (checkPermission ())
            {
                Toast.makeText(Scanner.this, "Permission is granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else
            {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission ()
    {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Scanner. this, CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private void requestPermission()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String permission[] , int grantResults[])
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA :

            if (grantResults.length > 0)
            {
                boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (cameraAccepted)
                {
                  Toast.makeText(Scanner.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Scanner.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    {
                        if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA))
                        {
                            displayAlertMessage("Yoou need to allow access for both permissions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions(new String[]{CAMERA} , REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            break;

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                if(checkPermission())
                {
                    if(scannerView == null)
                    {
                       scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                       setContentView(scannerView);
                    }
                    scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
                    scannerView.startCamera();
                }
                else
                {
                  requestPermission();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
           scannerView.stopCamera();
        }

        public void displayAlertMessage(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)

        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Scanner.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();


        }




        @Override
    public void handleResult(final Result result) {
        final String scanResult = result.getText();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("SUITABLE");
        builder.setPositiveButton("SCAN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
             scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(Scanner.this);
            }
        });

        builder.setNeutralButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(scanResult));
               startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        builder.setMessage(scanResult);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();





    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if the scanresult is in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322659/if-the-scanresult-is-in-the-database)